# TortoiseGit RESET resets ALL files in that Repo, correct?

Tags: tortoisegit

Just wanted to confirm this:

If I do a Reset, that [reset](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html) ALL the files in the repo to that version?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit resets affect the whole working tree and not individual files.

It depends on the "reset " variant. The "hard" variant resets all files to a specific version, "mixed" only resets the index and "soft" only resets the `HEAD` "pointer".

See [help](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html) and the [Git manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).